# Rethinking user controls and sessions

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, user-controls

Throughout my application I generally use a lot of server/user controls (both ASCX and VB server controls) that work with update panels.  These controls regularly make updates to both themselves and the applications database.  A common control I might have is a control similar to a gridview.  To persist data across update panel's update I will store the dataset (a list of objects) in a session and read/write to is as needed.

I've recently come to a point, though, that the memory needed to do this on a given page is exceeding the memory allocation on IIS.  As such, I need to start thinking about how I can redesign these controls.

Is there a better solution to persisting data across partial postbacks than using sessions?  I don't have the options to use any other session types, other than inProc (no db session or server farm session).  Would using caching of these datasets be a better option?

Thanks for any advice

jason

Comment: For your GridView-like controls are you doing custom paging or storing the entire grid's data in Session cache?

Comment: I'm storing pagination in in a session state, not cache.  Should I use caching instead?

Comment: Session state and session cache are the same thing, they store data about an individual session, by default, in the server's memory. Application cache however stores all user's data in memory and survives beyond a user's session. I think you need to look at what data you do not need to cache in Session, as opposed to looking at different techniques for caching, as you stated you are handcuffed to InProcess session caching techniques. Another idea is to look at removing items from Session when the user navigates away from a page, I know this can be difficult to capture in certain situations.